# access `IValueProvider` or `ModelBinder` in ActionFilter/IResultFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm creating a `IResultFilter` that automatic detect some query parameters and write paging info to the header and also process the result (if result is `PagedResponse<T>` or a `ObjectResult.Value` is `IEnumerable<T>` then I will paging the result and also add paging info to the header  and all that happen in `PagedObjectResult`)

current I manually bind my `PageRequestParameter` with `context.HttpContext.Request.Query["PageSize"]`, but is there a way to use `IValueProvider` or `Modelbinder` to get my `PageRequestParameter` object ?

Comment: I'm not sure about IResultFilter, but IActionFilter gives you the [ActionArguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.actionexecutingcontext.actionarguments) property.

Comment: @MarkG that doesn't help, `ActionArguments` are defined in action method , I need to detect the parameter whatever from querystring or form post , I see the source code of `TryUpdateModelAsync` , and it create a `IValueProvider` from `ControllerContext`/`ControllerDescriptor` , but in `ResultFilter` there only `ActionDescriptor`

Comment: @John See https://stackoverflow.com/q/56465398/2076531.

Comment: @MattM  they are all about `ActionParameter` instead of `ValueProvider`, the different between them is `ActionParameter` is define in Action Method,  but `ValueProvider` is about get value from `QueryString/FormCollection`